# git version control with local files

Tags: git, version-control

Ok I have a project in a folder called `mywebsite` which is located in my documents folder on my mac. How do I use git to version control this folder??

Every time I try something I end up with a fatal error of some sort and it's really annoying me now, can you help?

I do `git init`, then `mkdir` and then I've tried adding and cloning the files to no avail.

```
git init 
git mkdir mywebsite 
cd mywebsite 
git clone file://localhost/Users/me/Documens/sites/mywebsite 
fatal '/Users/me/Documens/sites/mywebsite' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please help!

Comment: For me it just works so can you give the detail of the steps and the errors

Comment: git init
git mkdir mywebsite
cd mywebsite
git clone file://localhost/Users/me/Documens/sites/mywebsite
fatal '/Users/me/Documens/sites/mywebsite' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: I am confused are you creating a new git repository or trying to get files from another? If the former whey git clone?

Answer (score 4):

If you have already files in '`mywebsite`':

```
cd /Users/me/Documens/sites/mywebsite
git init . # note the final '.'
```

then do a `git status` to see what needs to be added.

```
git add .
git status # check what has been added
git commit -m "first commit"
```

---

If you haven't any file yet, you can:

```
cd /Users/me/Documens/sites/
git init mywebsite
cd mywebsite # you are now in an empty git repo
```

Comment: See also http://progit.org/book/ch2-1.html. You don't need to clone here. And `git mkdir` doesn't exist.